# How can I send a message to a Chrome extension from an App Engine server?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to be able to send messages from an App Engine server to a Chrome extension. When the Chrome extension receives a message, it should increment the badge over the icon. Is it possible to send messages directly, or do I have to poll the server continuously from the extension?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the Cloud Messaging API, specifically [`chrome.gcm` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/gcm).

This would be the best way to notify the extension from the server side, and can be a two-way communication channel.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried looking through the GCM docs (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/cloudMessaging#receive_messages), but I can't figure out how to send a message from my App Engine server to my Chrome extension. The docs have info about sending messages the other way, as well as receiving messages within the extension, but not sending messages from the server. It's also unclear whether messages can be sent from an arbitrary app engine server. Do you know of a code sample that does this? Thank you!

Comment: You need to read the [GCM documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) too to integrate with your server. In particular, this [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html).